# openssl/bn.h: No such file or directory

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, openssl

I am totally new to Obj-C, and trying to compile Big Number related Objective C files

The function was easy, just to initialize a big number and use NSLog to print it out.

I used

```
#import <openssl/bn.h>
```

but the xcode always displays me an error:

openssl/bn.h: No such file or directory.

I tried to find out if the .h file were missing, and typed locate in my terminal:

> $ locate bn.h 
>   /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/openssl/bn.h
>   /usr/include/openssl/bn.h
>   /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/txt/hyph-bn.hyp.txt

It seemed I have the bn.h file, but why the xcode kept me from compiling?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that the OpenSSL headers are part of the Mac OS X environment, not part of the iOS environment. I you want OpenSSL for iOS, you need to compile it yourself. You'll find some help [there](https://github.com/st3fan/ios-openssl) (or alternatively [there](http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-inclusion-of-openssl-into-iphone-app-projects/)).

Comment: Thank u! Did you meant that OpenSSL is included in the MacOS environment but not yet in the CocoaTouch? I'll try those OpenSSL ports, thank you very much!

Comment: @ss1271: That's what I meant.

Comment: I am using Xcode 5 and i am unable to resolve the issue.Can u please help me?

Answer (score 21):

I had this exact problem, tried `libcurl4-openssl-dev` which didn't work, but found elsewhere that the following is the exact and proper solution:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Jessie trying to compile hostapd, but I'm pretty sure the solution is generic across a wide range of distributions and projects, particularly if you swap `apt-get` for `yum` or other package manager.

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 9):

To use openssl/bn.h on Linux:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```